# JSZip: Get content of file in zip from file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jszip

I want to get the content of a zip from input with JSZip.
I can read the title of my file but how do I get the content

I tried with jQuery:

```
$('.upload-input').on('change', function($event) {
 var $file = $event.target.files[0];
 JSZip.loadAsync($file).then(function($content) {
  alert($content.files["css/style.css"].async('text'));
 })
});
```

return: [object Promise]

What can I do to get the plain text

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jyuy7q6j/

THX!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`async`, like `loadAsync` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Here you can chain them:

```
$('.upload-input').on('change', function($event) {
 var $file = $event.target.files[0];
 JSZip.loadAsync($file).then(function($content) {
  // if you return a promise in a "then", you will chain the two promises
  return $content.files["css/style.css"].async('text');
 }).then(function (txt) {
   alert(txt);
 });
});
```

Comment: Oh, very easy :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I forgot about `files[...].async`, so here's my solution (with a little bit of traversing thru the file):

```js
var worldChars = Array.from(zip.files["world.txt"]._data.compressedContent)
var world = ""
for (var ch of worldChars) {
    world += String.fromCharCode(ch)
}
```